# Present attached sheet on MacOS SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'd like to present a sheet descending from the toolbar's bottom edge in a SwiftUI MacOS app. How can I specify that attachment point?

The methods below present a sheet at the view's center.

I had thought attachment was implied in .beginSheet(). Answers I see discussing this use Storyboards, but I'd like to stick to code.

```swift
struct SomeView: View {

    func presentsSheetAtWindowCenter() {
        guard let mainWindow = NSApp.mainWindow else { return }
        let host = NSHostingController(rootView: someView)
        let sheetWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: host)
        mainWindow.beginSheet(sheetWindow) { (response) in
            //
        }
    }
    
    func presentsSheetAtWindowCenterToo() {
        guard let mainCVC = NSApp.mainWindow?.contentViewController else { return }
        let host = NSHostingController(rootView: someView)
        mainCVC.presentAsSheet(host)
    }

}
```

Comment: Curious as to why someone decided to downvote without comment? Is this an inappropriate question somehow and I'm clueless about how to behave?

Comment: Native SwiftUI is to basic for this. You have to figure out how to create what you want programmatically “the old way” and then wrap it in a NSViewRepresentable.

Comment: Ok. I figured with the reference NSApp provides any calls on that main window would be handled normally. I'll just move the app to the non-SwiftUI App lifecycle or roll my own roll out, which isn't hard.

Comment: I assume you're talking about new BigSur sheet appearance. It is as designed now.

Comment: @Asperi. Didn't realize that was among the useful UI elements removed. In SwiftUI the sheet doesn't animate on dismiss, so rolling own or using the main window to present is cleaner. Thanks for letting me know.